# Refactoring implementation of multiple classes having common code (With DI)

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

I have multiple subsystems inside 1 big system. So every subsystem has it's own BAL and DAL implementation. Now the BAL(s) have significant logic but the DAL basically had similar code so I refactored it into one generic DAL class which is now used across all the subsystems. Something like this:

Let's assume subsystem names as A and B

```
public class DalA
{
    private IGenericDal genericDal;

    public DalA( IGenericDal injectedGenericDal)
    {
        this.genericDal = injectedGenericDal;
    }

    public bool DoSomeDBWorkForA()
    {
        return genericDal.CommonDalMethod();
    }
}


public class DalB
{
    private IGenericDal genericDal;

    public DalB(IGenericDal injectedGenericDal)
    {
        this.genericDal = injectedGenericDal;
    }

    public bool DoSomeDBWorkForB()
    {
       return genericDal.CommonDalMethod();
    }
}
```

Now the DI part of injecting generic DAL is important from unit testing point of view, so the BAL(s) have to inject the generic DAL object. So now the BAL is unnecessarily being aware of generic DAL object just because of the refactoring and DI requirements, which ideally it should not be (specially in case of refactoring).

Also one of my friends pointed out that the DAL(s) of subsystem A and B are doing nothing so we should probably get rid of them and call generic DAL itself, but in my opinion it reduces flexibility as tomorrow DAL of A might want to do some logging or some other special action which B or even C might not subscribe to.

So what do you guys think? Does anybody have a better refactored implementation where the DI, the separation of concerns (i.e. BAL of A is only aware of DAL of A and not generic DAL object) and flexibility (having different DAL(s) for all the subsystems) are intact.

One of the ways that I thought of was to have 2 constructors in DAL of A and B, so that from BAL we can call without injecting generic DAL and from Unit Test I can inject Generic DAL object.

Comment: IMHO, It's wrong to have multiple sub-systems inside one system (solution) those have all parts of a system; Using Micro-Services is better idea instead or changing sub-systems to modules ;).

Comment: @shA.t That's a good suggestion but in this case I can't afford the increased latency due to Micro-services implementation ;) So in that case what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the DAL(s) of subsystem A and B are doing nothing so we should probably get rid of them and call generic DAL itself, but in my opinion it reduces flexibility as tomorrow DAL of A might want to do some logging or some other special action which B or even C might not subscribe to.

Classes should be [open for extension but closed to modification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). This means that adding logging should not mean you need to alter the DAL of A. You should be able to do this by creating a decorator that wraps the generic DAL. The same holds for other cross-cutting concerns.

So this flexibility isn't IMO a strong argument for keeping the extra layers of indirection in.

Comment: So you are saying removing the intermediate DAL(s) for the time being is the way to go and modification should be handled via Decorator, but don't you think the DAL(s) across the world rarely deal with much logic so in a broader sense shouldn't DAL(s) always (or at least oftenly) be designed this way as most of the applications have multiple modules (therefore multiple DAL(s)) to deal with?

Comment: @RachitPandey: Yes, considering the supplied information, I advice the removal of the intermediate layer. I can't really comment on how "DAL(s) across the world" are designed, since there are too many common flavors with this.

Comment: I agree with removal of intermediate layers now, but there will be one anomaly which I would like your thoughts upon. If I am calling the generic DAL directly from BAL then I do need to provide some "DAL specific parameters" like SP name etc, which I think BAL shouldn't really be aware of. Also I can't remove these parameters from generic DAL in order for it to stay Generic.

Comment: @RachitPandey if you need to supply these pareters from the BAL, it means that your DAL is leaking implementation details. In other words, your DAL is a leaky abstraction. Those values should be encapsulated within your DAL.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, if I go on to make my DAL implementation specific then it wouldn't remain generic anymore. I'll look for more ways to achive this, thanks a lot for all your time and suggestions they really cleared a lot of doubts.

Comment: @RachitPandey: Well, if the generic DAL implementation talks to different stored procedured that have a different schema (opposed to calling the same SP in mutliple databases with the exact schema), that indicates that you actually need multiple abstractions. You would be violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) otherwise.